# wpf listview unselect items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have two ListView. The main idea is raise `TestCommand` when user select item from `FirstList` and `TestTestCommand` when user select item from `SecondList`. In this case how to unselect item from `FirstList` when user select item in `SecondList`, and uselect in `SecondList` when user select in `FirstList`.
I tried to insert `<ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="FirstList" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"></ei:ChangePropertyAction>` into  `<i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged"/>` but this is bad idea.

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Width="200" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="FirstList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding .}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainWindow }}}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListView>
    <ListBox Width="200" Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="SecondList" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding .}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TestTestCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainWindow }}}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

code

```
namespace WpfApplication129
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new Data();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public class Data
{
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand TestTestCommand { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
    public Data()
    {
        TestCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Test());
        TestTestCommand = new RelayCommand(() => TestTest());
        Items = new List<string>();
        Items.Add("first");
    }
    public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Running");
    }
    public void TestTest()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TestRunning");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In wpf it is advisable to use MVVM. And in MVVM you bind `SelectedItem1` to SelectedItem of first ListView and `SelectedItem2` to second one. Then you have possibility to do anything with selection indirectly by changing `SelectedItemX` in ViewModel (e.g. when processing command you can *unselect* second listview by setting `SelectedItem2 = null`).

Comment: Try <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="FirstList" PropertyName="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}"></ei:ChangePropertyAction>. If it's ok for, I'll post answer

Comment: I agree with you. But when in viewmodel i should change "SelectedItem1" it shoud raise <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged"> and then TestCommand. How to avoid this?

Comment: to VMaleev i tried to make what you advising. But it has chain reaction. in the end of reaction it unselect item in both list's. I need only in opposit list.

Comment: I'd recommend you to handle LostFocus event to unselect items

Comment: Sinatr i done how you sad. Post answer and i will accept it.